# Event handler to use when a text input has been updated by javascript rather than keypress / copy/paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to read the value of a text input every time it is updated. It is being updated by craftyclicks postcode finder, hence there is no typing/keypress in the box, nor is there any copying/pasting. I have tried:

```
$('#AddressL1').change(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    console.log
});
```

and also:

```
$('#AddressL1').on('input', function(e) {
    val = $(this).val();
    console.log
});
```

...but neither of these work unless I update the box by typing something manually. I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: I would appreciate it if whoever voted this question down could explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While updating the value of an input field via script, the events are not fired, you need to trigger the events manually like

```
$(input).val(value).change()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is being passed into `val()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Marc it was just a placeholder for what value you want to assign

Comment: In this particular situation, I'm afraid I don't have control of how the value is assigned, I just need to be able to read it to a variable so that I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: I tried the following, but it did not work....

`$('#AddressL1').val().change(function(){`
`val = $(this).val();`
     `console.log(val);`
    `});`

Comment: Browser console shows the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'change'`

Comment: @Marc calling `.val()` without any argument will be considered as a getter method and then it will return the value of the input field which does not have the `change` method, so it should be `$('#AddressL1').change(function () {
    val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
});`

Comment: I think that's the same as one of the examples in my question. If so, that only reads anything out to the console upon manually typing into the box, and not if it is set by script. Do you have any other thoughts? Thanks for the help.